# Subsurface Modifier Is acting strange

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]So I am new to blender and am following the 2.8 donut tutorial (what a surprise haha). I got to the step of the subdivision surface modifier, but when I add it to the donut to smooth things out a bit my donut looks VERY weird in edit mode (note that Blender Guru's does NOT look like this):
[image]

Any help in fixing and understanding this issue would be great!

Comment: Looks like there are some faces intersecting either from this or a different object. Can you post a screenshot of your entire screen with the 3D view set to wireframe mode?

Comment: I have edited the post to add the picture. It happened as soon as I added the modifier so I'm not sure why

Comment: I see, you've indented the vertex, which is why the smoothed surface created by the subsurface modifier is visible. If that bothers you while editing you can disable the modifier from displaying in edit mode or move the vertices slightly outward.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertices in this area are causing an indent in the surface. When the subsurface modifier is applied, the subdivided surface has a smoother transition and intersects the coarse mesh in edit mode. This is completely normal.

A basic torus
[image: Torus]

One vertex moved along the z-axis to create a dent
[image: Indent]

You can hide the subsurface modifier for the edit mode.

[image: Disable subsurface modifier display in edit mode]